# Generate constant labels with dynamic values in angular with typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have to convert all the labels in my application to label constants.

The HTML in some areas have dynamic content like this `This label has '1' dynamic values` where the `'1'` is subject to change according to the component or a different application state.

I would have to add 2 different values in my labelConstants like this

```
label_1: 'This label has \'',

label_2: '\' dynamic values'
```

and generate the string like this

`let string = LabelConst.label_1 + '1' + LabelConst.label_2;`

An idea I had for solving this was to add a value in the label constant like this

`label_1: 'This label has '%s' dynamic values'`

and then while generating the value for the labels use a common function to replace the `%s` value like this in my typescript code,

`let requiredLabel = insertDynamicValues(LabelConst.label_1, '3');`

where the function `insertDynamicValues()` would replace `%s` in the label constant and return `This label has '3' dynamic values`.

Is there a more efficient/better way to do this (without external libraries)?

Answer (score 1):

I have this approach:

```
'The label has %0 dynamic value'
```

and TypeScript code:

```
  public static replacePlaceholder(text: string, words: string[], placeholder: string = '%'): string {
const replaceValue = (result: string, value: string, i: number): string => {
  return result.replace(`${placeholder}${i}`, String(value));
};

return words.reduce(replaceValue, text);
```

}

That way I can use multiple placeholders in one string. Example:

```
`We have %0 apples and %1 oranges`
```

Comment: thanks but I had already mentioned this method in the answer, can you suggest a different vanilla ts solution?

Comment: Maybe this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: sorry, but template literals would not make much sense, as I would require 2 labels like the first method

Comment: Got it. I might be wrong, but I don't see there is a way to handle it with a built-in browser solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a library like mustache (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mustache)  or handlebars (https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars) for this, although I am not sure if this is an overkill for your use case. This basically depends on how complex the labels should be.

Comment: sorry, I don't think I'd be able to add external libraries for this, but both of these libraries  sound very cool, is there any vanilla alternatives you can suggest?